# Why this gradient is not properly rendering on Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, linear-gradients

I added a simple linear gradient using CSS to a `<div>`. For some reason, it's not working on Chrome, although, it works fine on Safari.

The CSS rules look like this:

```
background-color: #043a5f;
background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,#043a5f,rgba(30,113,212,0));
background-position: top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 400px;
```

The expected result is a light blue gradient over a darker blue background. In the following image, on the left, there is Safari (which looks good), and Chrome on the right.

[image: Safari vs. Chrome rendering]

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate that: https://jsfiddle.net/straube/13rsq9y4/

P.S.: I'm running Chrome 88.0.4324.96 and Safari 14.0 (15610.1.28.1.9, 15610) on MacOS 10.15.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a Safari bug, actually. `rgba(30, 113, 212, 0)` is the same "color" as `rgba(12, 34, 56, 0)` (for example), because there is only one "color" with the alpha value `0`: the `transparent` "color".

So Chrome (and Firefox) are trying to interpolate between `#043a5f` (the background color, effectively invisible), and `transparent` (effectively invisible). Because `transparent` has no hue, the only variable that changes throughout the gradient is the alpha channel value.

You can specify three steps in your gradient to achieve the desired result:

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, rgb(30 113 212), transparent);
```

Comment: It makes sense. However, I intentionally wanted it to make 2 interpolations: from color A to B **AND** from opaque (opacity: 1) to transparent (opacity: 0). Which is what I'm getting on Safari. But I understand this is open to interpretation by browser developers.

Comment: BTW, design tools -- like Figma -- give me the same result as Safari does.

Comment: Awesome! It worked. I only had to use `rgba(30, 113, 212, 0.5)` as the middle color to get exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems the different browsers might be blending the `background-color` and `background-image` gradient differently.

You could maybe add something like `background-blend-mode: screen;` or maybe `background-blend-mode: overlay;` to try and get similiar behavior in both browsers

Comment: I just tried other modes as you suggested. I see different results, but not exactly what I wanted.